# Python numpy : linalg.pinv() too imprecise

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, precision, inverse

I've been working with `numpy` matrices in an algorithm lately and I've encountered a problem :

I use 3 matrices in total.

```
m1 = [[  3   2   2 ...   3   2   3]
      [  3   3   3 ...   2   2   2]
      [500 501 502 ... 625 626 627]
      ...
      [623 624 625 ... 748 749 750]
      [624 625 626 ... 749 750 751]
      [625 626 627 ... 750 751 752]]
```

`m1` is a (128,128) *singular* square matrix. The first two rows are seemingly random sequences of 2s and 3s. The next rows are filled algorithmically counting from 500, adding one for each row and for each column starting from the third row, first column.

```
m2 = [[  2   3 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  2   2 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  3   2 500 ... 623 624 625]
      ...
      [  2   3 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  2   2 500 ... 623 624 625]
      [  3   2 500 ... 623 624 625]]
```

`m2` is also a (128,128) singular square matrix. This time, the random sequences are attributed to the first two columns. The rest of each row is filled with 500, 501, 502, 503, and so on.

```
m3 = [[     790      784   157500 ...   196245   196560   196875]
      [     804      811   161000 ...   200606   200928   201250]
      [  180501   180411 36064000 ... 44935744 45007872 45080000]
      ...
      [  219861   219771 43936000 ... 54744256 54832128 54920000]
      [  220181   220091 44000000 ... 54824000 54912000 55000000]
      [  220501   220411 44064000 ... 54903744 54991872 55080000]]
```

`m3 = m1*m2`

So what I wanted to do was to recover `m2` using `m1` and `m3`. Theoretically, all I had to do was execute the following code `m2 = (m1**-1)*m3`. Unfortunately, due to `m1` being a singular matrix, it was not possible to calculate its inverse and, even if it were possible, the matrix was too big, causing numerous numerical imprecisions.

Instead, I decided to use the [Moore-Penrose Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of `m1`, which doesn't require the matrix to be non-singular and, similarly to the Inverse, makes it theoretically possible to recover `m2`, using `np.linalg.pinv(m1) * m3`.

Once again, I use the term "theoretically" because, as it turns out, `numpy` is too imprecise when it comes to such calculations with big matrices, and here's the result I obtain for `m2`:

```
[[  2.46207616   2.48959603 500.         ... 623.         624.
  625.        ]
 [  2.38612549   2.61197086 500.         ... 623.         624.
  625.        ]
 [  2.38711085   2.6125801  500.         ... 623.         624.
  625.        ]
 ...
 [  2.61998539   2.37184747 500.         ... 623.         624.
  625.        ]
 [  2.54403472   2.4942223  500.         ... 623.         624.
  625.        ]
 [  2.62195611   2.37306595 500.         ... 623.         624.
  625.        ]]
```

As you can see, the whole 'filler' part of `m1` is correctly calculated, no problem with that. However, it seemed to have problems with the first two columns, and rounding the numbers to 2s and 3s gives me an incorrect `m2`.

I'm looking for a way to make the `np.linalg.pinv()` method way more precise with its float calculations so it can obtain the proper values for the sequences, as those are very important.

By doing some research, I learned that `np.linalg.pinv()` has an argument called `rcond`, described as the following :

> **rcond :** *(…) array_like of float*
>
> Cutoff for small singular values. Singular values smaller (in modulus) than rcond * largest_singular_value (again, in modulus) are set to zero. Broadcasts against the stack of matrices

`rcond` is, by default, set to `1e-15`. I thought that reducing that number even further could help with imprecision. `1e-16` wasn't enough and, starting from `1e-17`, I get very weird values, such as those :

```
[[ 3.000e+00  3.000e+00  5.000e+02 ...  6.230e+02  6.240e+02  6.250e+02]
 [ 1.100e+01  4.000e+00  1.840e+02 ...  1.722e+03  2.032e+03  1.831e+03]
 [-3.000e+00 -5.000e+00 -4.030e+02 ... -1.232e+03 -7.400e+02 -1.272e+03]
 ...
 [ 1.100e+01  1.200e+01  2.164e+03 ...  4.030e+03  4.872e+03  1.873e+03]
 [-1.200e+01 -9.000e+00 -1.618e+03 ... -3.240e+03 -2.519e+03 -4.167e+03]
 [ 2.000e+01  2.600e+01  4.535e+03 ...  5.165e+03  5.881e+03  5.189e+03]]
```

So, basically, I'm stuck, I don't know how to increase precision.
Worst part is, I have a module that can dramatically increase float precision, it's called `mpmath` and also has matrices that appear to work even better with my algorithm as the `numpy` ones. But `mpmath` doesn't have a method to calculate pseudoinverses, and `numpy` doesn't adapt its own float precision to the value set with `mpmath`.

Would you have any suggestions I could try to get the correct `m2` using the pseudoinverse method ?

Comment: If m1 is square there isn't any difference between taking the inverse and the pseudo inverse.  You have a non-invertible matrix, taking the pseudo inverse using any amount of precision doesn't change that.

Comment: You already know all but the first 2 rows of M2, right? You can use this knowledge to better recover it

Comment: By what metric are you deeming numpy as imprecise? Does `m1 @ m2_estimated == m3`, roughly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what bites you is not lack of precision but simply the fact that your system is massively underdetermined. `m1` will typically have rank `4` and a `124D` nullspace. In other words each column of `m2_recon` has 124 degrees of freedom that are not constrained by the requirement `m1@x == m3`

Comment: @user2699 What I don't understand is, how come `numpy` doesn't return an Exception for Singular Matrices ? It does that usually.
@Eric I might try to use information about `m2` to better recover its first two lines, but I'm still not sure how to do it. Then again, if I had _slight_ imprecision that wouldn't be a problem, but, to give you an idea : `m3[0] = [[     780      791   160000 ...   199360   199680   200000]]` ; `(m1 @ m2_estimated)[0] = [[2.53173393e+02 3.53364135e+02 6.06764737e+04 ... 1.42436998e+05
  9.72372952e+04 8.91055922e+04]`
@Paul Panzer What would you recommend ?

Comment: @BlackyuSylvean, I stated that poorly.  `pinv` provides a result for non-invertible matrices, but it doesn't allow recovering the original matrix any more than using `inv` would.

Comment: @BlackyuSylvean 1) `pinv` is defined and useful for singular matrices, an exception would not be called for.  2) columns of `m2` are completely independent. Knowing columns 2 and beyond tells you nothing about columns 0 and 1. 3) As I said your problem is underdetermined. What you are trying to achieve is impossible.

Comment: Alright, I'll try something else. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your troubles have got nothing to do with `pinv` being accurate or not.

As you note yourself your matrices are massively rank deficient, `m1` has rank 4 or less, `m2` rank 3 or less. Hence your system `m1@x = m3` is underdetermined in the extreme and it is not possible to recover `m2`.

Even if we throw in all we know about the structure of `m2`, i.e. first two columns 3's and 2's, rest 500 counting upwards, there are a combiniatorially large number of solutions.

The script below finds them all if allowed enough time. In practice I didn't look beyond 32x32 matrices which in the run shown below yielded
15093381006 different valid reconstructions `m2'` that satisfy `m1@m2' = m3` and the structural constraints I just mentioned.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def make(n, offset=500):
    offset -= 2
    res1 = np.add.outer(np.arange(n), np.arange(offset, offset+n))
    res1[:2] = np.random.randint(2, 4, (2, n))
    res2 = np.add.outer(np.zeros(n, int), np.arange(offset, offset+n))
    res2[:, :2] = np.random.randint(2, 4, (n, 2))
    return res1, res2

def subsets(L, n, mn, mx, prepend=[]):
    if n == 0:
        if mx >= mn:
            yield prepend
    elif n == 1:
        for l in L[L.searchsorted(mn):L.searchsorted(mx, 'right')]:
            yield prepend + [l]
    else:
        ps = L.cumsum()
        ps[n:] -= ps[:-n]
        ps = ps[n-1:]
        for i in range(L.searchsorted(mn - np.sum(L[len(L)-n+1:])),
                       ps.searchsorted(mx, 'right')):
            yield from subsets(L[i+1:], n-1, mn - L[i], mx - L[i],
                               prepend = prepend + [L[i]])

def solve(m1, m3, ci=0, offset=500):
    n, n = m1.shape
    col = m3.T[ci]
    n3s = col[3] - col[2] - 2 * n
    six = col[2] - offset * (col[3] - col[2]) - n * (n-1)
    idx = np.lexsort(m1[:2])
    m1s = m1[:2, idx]
    sm = m1s[1].searchsorted(2.5)
    sl = m1s[0, :sm].searchsorted(2.5)
    sr = sm + m1s[0, sm:].searchsorted(2.5)
    n30 = n - sl - sr + sm
    n31 = n - sm
    n330 = col[0] - 4*n - 2*n3s - 2*n30
    n331 = col[1] - 4*n - 2*n3s - 2*n31
    for n333 in range(max(0, n330 - sm + sl, n331 - sr + sm),
                      min(n - sr, n330, n331) + 1):
        n332 = n330 - n333
        n323 = n331 - n333
        n322 = n3s - n332 - n323 - n333
        mx333 = six - idx[sl:sl+n332].sum() - idx[sm:sm+n323].sum() \
                - idx[:n322].sum()
        mn333 = six - idx[sm-n332:sm].sum() - idx[sr-n323:sr].sum() \
                - idx[sl-n322:sl].sum()
        for L333 in subsets(idx[sr:], n333, mn333, mx333):
            mx332 = six - np.sum(L333) - idx[sm:sm+n323].sum() \
                - idx[:n322].sum()
            mn332 = six - np.sum(L333) - idx[sr-n323:sr].sum() \
                - idx[sl-n322:sl].sum()
            for L332 in subsets(idx[sl:sm], n332, mn332, mx332,
                                prepend=L333):
                mx323 = six - np.sum(L332) - idx[:n322].sum()
                mn323 = six - np.sum(L332) - idx[sl-n322:sl].sum()
                for L323 in subsets(idx[sm:sr], n323, mn323, mx323,
                                    prepend=L332):
                    ex322 = six - np.sum(L323)
                    yield from subsets(idx[:sl], n322, ex322, ex322,
                                       prepend=L323)

def recon(m1, m3, ci=0, offset=500):
    n, n = m1.shape
    nsol = nfp = 0
    REC = []
    for i3s in solve(m1, m3, ci, offset):
        rec = np.full(n, 2)
        rec[i3s] = 3
        if not np.all(m3.T[ci] == m1@rec):
            print('!', rec, m3.T[ci], m1@rec)
            nfp += 1
        else:
            nsol += 1
            REC.append(rec)
    print('col', ci, ':',  nsol, 'solutions,', nfp, 'false positives')
    return np.array(REC)

def full_recon(m1, m3, offset=500, subsample=10):
    n, n = m1.shape
    col0, col1 = (recon(m1, m3, i, offset) for i in (0, 1))
    yield col0.shape[0], col1.shape[0]
    if not subsample is None:
        col0, col1 = (col[np.random.choice(col.shape[0], subsample)]
                      if col.shape[0] > subsample else col
                      for col in (col0, col1))
    print('col 0', col0)
    print('col 1', col1)
    for c0, c1 in itertools.product(col0, col1):
        out = np.add.outer(np.zeros(n, int), np.arange(offset-2, offset+n-2))
        out[:, :2] = np.c_[c0, c1]
        yield out

def check(m1, m3, offset=500, subsample=10):
    for cnt, m2recon in enumerate(full_recon(m1, m3, offset, subsample)):
        if cnt == 0:
            tot0, tot1 = m2recon
            continue
        assert np.all(m3 == m1@m2recon)
    print(cnt, 'solutions verified out of', tot0, 'x', tot1, '=', tot0 * tot1)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> m1, m2 = make(32)
>>> check(m1, m1@m2)
col 0 : 133342 solutions, 0 false positives
col 1 : 113193 solutions, 0 false positives
col 0 [[2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2]
 [2 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3]
 [2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2]
 [3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2]
 [3 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2]
 [3 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 3]]
col 1 [[2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 3]
 [2 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 3]
 [3 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2]
 [2 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 3]
 [3 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2]
 [3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2]
 [2 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2]
 [2 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 3]
 [3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3]
 [3 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 3]]
100 solutions verified out of 133342 x 113193 = 15093381006
```

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. Does that mean that higher matrix ranks could help solve these with better precision ?
Also, I get an error when trying your script :
`File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 284, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`

Comment: @BlackyuSylvean don't use `matrix`, use `array`.

Comment: Ah, okay, yes, I think I see the problem. I'll attempt to recover matrices in a different way. Thanks for your help and your program !